# Filter similar records in a table using Dblookupcombobox

Tags: delphi, ms-access-2010, delphi-7

I have a `dblookupCombobox` that is connected to an access table `feeds` using a `datasource` and `adoquery`. I have used the listsource, keyfield, and listfield properties to connect it to the `feeds` table field name `feedtype`. problem is that `dblookupCombobox`shows repetitive records. Is it possible to filter the records and show only one record? Or how else can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The listsource and listfield should really come from another table, even if it's constructed table such as

```
SELECT DISTINCT feedtype FROM feeds AS lookup.
```

Create another adoquery and use that to get the list of `DISTINCT` values, then use that for your listsource.

I always create a specific lookup table where users can manage the valid entries.